# angular js getting data from laravel and print it

Tags: angularjs

Hi I'am trying a simple example of using a controller and a factory to get some data back to the view but for some reason I can't print it.

I managed to get the ajax call to work. 
If I type the

```
$scope.sampleStyles = [{ sample: 'text here', text : 'dasdas'}
```

and don't use the ajax call it works

UPDATE: if I add an alert before assigning to my scope it works (ajax has time to do his thing)
anyone know how to overcome that?

CODE:

```
var packageApp = angular.module("packageApp", []);
```

packageApp.controller("MyController", function($scope, myFactory){

```
$scope.sampleStyles = [];  

function init(){
    $scope.sampleStyles = myFactory.getSampleStyles();  
} 
init();

});

packageApp.factory('myFactory', function($http, $log){
var factory = {};

var sampleStyles = [];
var tempData = {};

factory.update = function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/account/fetch-sample-styles',
        data: {
            source: 'ajax'
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
            tempData = data;   
        }
    });


    alert(tempData);    
    sampleStyles = tempData;
} 


factory.getSampleStyles = function(){ 
    factory.update();
    return sampleStyles;

};

return factory;
 });
```

Comment: code added. tried different ways so a bit messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the AngularJs [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) service? If so it will return a promise which you then operate on. Here is more on [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q) from the AngularJs docs.

My guess is, you are using an ajax.get(...) with a success callback defined inside. The problem is probably due to the success callback not belonging to the "AngularJs world."

To fix this, you need to tell AngularJs that its scope has changed. Use the [`$[Root]scope.$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply) function, and have the scope injected into your service as a dependency.

Something like this inside the factory:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/some/end/:point", 
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.sampleStyles = data; // etc
        });
    }
});
```

I strongly recommend that you look into the `$http` service, it makes the above code much nicer, and is designed to play nice with the $scope.

```
$http.get("/api/end/point").then(function(response) {
    // response.data points at the page data sent back, assuming that your
    // api endpoint sends back JSON of the likes of
    // { status: "SUCCESS", styles: [...] }
    $scope.sampleStyles = response.data.styles;
});
```

**EDIT:**
Now that you posted some code, it seems like the root of your issue is based on the fact that the ajax get is an async call. Why are you even messing with using a temporary variable? Why not the following?

```
factory.update = function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/account/fetch-sample-styles',
        data: {
            source: 'ajax'
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
            sampleStyles = data;
        }
    });
}
```

If you really wanted to make the $.ajax call blocking, you can set `async: false` in the $.ajax properties.

**EDIT 2:**
Fixed some broken links, sorry I am a SO newb :(

Comment: thanks sabhiram after many many tries I got that example working using $q promise

Comment: $http doesn't want to play with my laravel for some reason

Comment: I'll give it a go though cheers. u open my eyes angular is not for rookies like me

Comment: You are most welcome. Don't give up on it, AngularJs can be very fun to play with. Although I am far from an "expert", I am fairly certain every expert out there was a rookie at some point :)

Comment: :) I also hope that they update the documentation and get it a bit more friendly!

Comment: About the edit: yea I was tried everything (used it for debug)

Comment: I manage to make $http work now (it didn't like laravel's profiler that was returning with every request). Cheers dude

Comment: Awesome! Glad I was of help.